# how do I get the list of contact folders for a user with MicrosoftGraph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-contacts

I can't get access to the other contact folders in a user's account, through the MSGraph API.

I am able to get the contacts in the default folder. But when I try to get the other contact folders for that same account with a GET request to this url

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com/contactfolders`

I get an empty array

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('user%domain.com')/contactFolders",
  "value": []
}
```

When I look at the decoded jwt I can see that I have `Contacts.ReadWrite` and `Contacts.ReadW` in the scopes. I believe that should be enough. Also since I can read contacts out of the default folder.  Which gives me the impression that my app is set up correctly in AZ AD.

What else am I missing?

Comment: The request you provide is listing the contact folders for the user. What's the exact for get the other contact folders you were using?

Comment: Are you sure the user has contact folders other than the default? If you only have the default folder, that API returns empty. Basically that API only returns "custom" folders.

Comment: yes, the user does have other "Contact" folders.

Comment: I am trying to list the other "contact" folders for that user. The URL I posted above is what I used. (Plus it had the token in the header.  )  Shouldn't that list other contact folders?

Comment: Could you try issuing the same call against the beta endpoint? I just want to confirm if you're seeing the same results.

Comment: Ah Ha.  Beta endpoint worked.  Is that what I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

Using the beta endpoint worked.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/user@domain.com/contactfolders